# React native bottom tab navigation error, brand new app from expo template

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I just created a new app using expo template, and when executed without any change to code it throws following error

```
    C02SW0WD:Projects user$ expo init testTabApp
? Choose a template: 
  ----- Managed workflow -----
  blank                 a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas 
  blank (TypeScript)    same as blank but with TypeScript configuration 
***❯ tabs                  several example screens and tabs using react-navigation*** 
  ----- Bare workflow -----
  minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started 
  minimal (TypeScript)  same as minimal but with TypeScript configuration
```

[image: error detail without any change in code]

As an additional test, I created a black project also using expo init (blank -> a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas), the app worked as expected... then I added bottom tab navigation required npms:

1. yarn add @react-navigation/native
2. yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
3. yarn add react-native-screens
4. yarn add react-native-safe-area-context

After that I create two empty screens and modified App.js to use bottom tab navigation as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Chat from './screens/Chat';
import Home from './screens/Home';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Once again, same error about "undefined is not a function (near '...Object.fromEntries...')"

Any thougts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The issue is fixed within the package, update it to the latest version. 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/51f4d11fdf4bd2bb06f8cd4094f051816590e62c

The method `Object.fromEntries` is missing.
Add `yarn add @babel/polyfill` and update your `.babelrc` file to use it:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
        "@babel/polyfill"
    ]
}
```

Should work after that, more info is available on the website https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill